# play sbt not starting on scala docker image

Tags: java, scala, docker, playframework, sbt

I am trying to run my play/scala app on docker image bitbucketpipelines/scala-sbt:scala-2.12. App starts but it exits right after without any error message (as if terminated normally).

```
root@db0eca2925cf:~# sbt -v -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m run < /dev/null
[process_args] java_version = '1.8'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-jar
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
run

[info] Loading project definition from /root/project
[info] Set current project to MyApp (in build file:/root/)
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[info] Generated messages files
[info] Generated messages files

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000          

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Stopping server...

[success] Total time: 24 s, completed Oct 13, 2017 4:35:44 AM
root@db0eca2925cf:~#
```

Anything I am missing? Here is how I created the container:

```
docker run -it \
        --volume=<my project root here>:/root \
        --workdir="/root" \
        --memory=4g --memory-swap=4g --memory-swappiness=0 \
        bitbucketpipelines/scala-sbt:scala-2.12 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-a stdin -a stdout -a stderr`.  See [foreground](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) in the docker docs.